# how to create custom pipe for images?

Tags: angular, pipe

I created an angular app that returns user profiles. these profiles sometimes have a profile image and sometimes not

if profile image is empty i want to display a placeholder image by using a pipe

i want to send the user image to the pipe and check if it's empty replace it with `assets/images/user.jpg` otherwise keep the user image

**empty-profile-image.pipe.ts**

```
 import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

 @Pipe({
 name: 'emptyProfileImage'
 })

 export class EmptyProfileImagePipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(contactImage: string): string {
    if (contactImage == ''){
      return "assets/images/user.jpg"
    }
    else{
      return "groupMember.contactImage";
    }
    }

 }
```

**user-profile.component.ts**

```
  <img class="user-image"
   src=" user.contactImage | emptyProfileImage">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try something like

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

 @Pipe({
 name: 'emptyProfileImage'
  })
 export class EmptyProfileImagePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(contactImage: string): string {
     return contactImage || yourplaceholderimagepath;
   }
 }
```

then in your html

```
 <img class="user-image"
   [src]=" user.contactImage | emptyProfileImage">
```

**note it should be `[src]` instead of `src`**

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ugawdw)

Comment: it  works in the first time  but when i reload the page i got an error  "The pipe 'emptyProfileImage' could not be found"

Comment: can you create stackblitz demo of your problem

Comment: @RenadMunhi so what's the problem then?also can you please upvote and mark this as ans if it works for you

Comment: sometimes i got images url like /bea/attachment/userimages/.jpg or /bea/attachment/userimages/userID.jpg , userid can be 1234 , 8975. when i was checking in html before using pipe i just did contactimage === " '' ? placeholderimagepath  but now when i'm using the pipe it's not working anymore

Comment: it's not an error it's the condition is not right , empty images are not being replaced by the placeholder

Comment: @RenadMunhi so you wanna say if you receive "" in image url then that should not be replaced by placeholder? or you please show me the code you were using before pipe

Answer (score 0):

Set the date image path as

```
<img [src]="user.contactImage | emptyProfileImage" >
```

And the pipe function as to return

```
return contactImage || "assets/images/user.jpg";
```